# Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Z not working in terminal

Tags: mac, terminal, backtrack

I setup a virtual pentest lab on my Mac.

When I am using lanmap2, every time I try to stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> it just types `^Z`, but if I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the entire terminal window closes.

Are there any commands that I can use to stop the process instead of using a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: There's a setting under Terminal's preferences -> Profiles -> Shell called "When the shell exits:" and it gives you the option to close or not close the terminal window.

Comment: What worked for me, was doing `Cmd + R`. Then those short cuts work again.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using a MAC keyboard <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>dot/period</kbd> should be equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for break.

For <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> for UnDo and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> for ReDo.

Refer to the Terminal Help > Keyboard Shortcuts

Comment: Nothing seams to work... I do not understand reason for ZSH. Is the way to replace it with something reliable?

Comment: Thank you! I've been dealing with this issue for some time. On mac, ctrl+c only suspends I guess because node processes continue to use their respective ports. Command+dot uses SIGINT and properly kills the process and port.

Answer (score 5):

I'd try `stty -a` in the Terminal, see what your cchars are mapped to. Make sure that susp (suspend) is mapped to Ctrl-Z (^Z) and intr (interrupt) to ^C.

Do you have any programs running that may 'steal' the keypress? Maybe `somecoolapp` uses Ctrl-Z to send a zebra Twitpic someplace.

Remember that Ctrl-C will close your window if all the processes under it go away. I don't know how you run your app, but if it replaces bash by using exec, then the 'Ctrl-C closes window' makes a bit more sense. Ctrl-C closes the foreground app, which is the only thing running, which closes the window.

To suspend the process, you could use another terminal window to send the signal. Find the process ID using either Activity Monitor or the `ps` command, and in the other window type `kill -STOP <processid>`. Unfortunately Activity Monitor doesn't seem to let you send just any signal, and SIGSTOP and SIGCONT are not in the list (at least on Snow Leopard, which is what I can check).

Answer (score 3):

How are you starting the program? If you double-click you're actually running two commands

```
 <program>; exit;
```

This will close the window after the program has executed.

If this is the case try launching `lanmap2`or whatever your program is in a new terminal window. This way `ctrl` + `c` will only close out of the program not the window.

As for `ctrl` + `z` I have yet to find anything that would stop that from working.

Comment: Is there a source that says that its actually running that two commands?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is `Ctrl+S`? That temporarily stops the output of the running program. `Ctrl+Z` suspends the program so you can go back to the shell and do something and then get back to the program again with the `fg` command.

Answer (score -1):

In a new terminal, use the [killall](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_killall.htm) command.

Comment: No im not trying to copy the command window, Im trying to stop the process so I can make a map of the networks. I'm new to all this so basically I might not be using the right terminology but, Im having a hard time trying to output the image from the ping results.

Comment: @Easton I edited my answer, try it out